# Changing the route behaviour but keeping the "Convention over Configuration"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, routes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.7 and in my application I have an `Users::Article` class (note that it is namespaced). In the `routes.rb` file it is stated as follow:

```
resources :users do
  resources :articles
end
```

I would like to set the route related to the `Users::Article` class so that I can access that at the URL `/articles`, `/articles/new`, `/articles/1` and  `/articles/1/edit` but I would like to still use the RoR *Convention over Configuration* "system". That is, I would like to use:

- `Users::ArticlesHelper`;
- `views/users/articles/<file_name>.html.erb` view files;
- named routes (`<name>_path` and `<name>_url`);
- and others "a là Ruby on Rails Way"...

**How can I do that?**

---

In few words, for example, I would like to refer to the `/articles/1` path but making the application to work exactly as it is considering the `users/<user_id>/articles/1` path.

Answer (score 0):

it's not an estetic matter, but it's related to parameters for routing.

you can use `/articles/:id` and then refer to the owner (User) inside controller.

in the second case `/users/:user_id/articles/:id` will pass 2 params to controller.

Answer (score 0):

From the [ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Resources docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-shallow):

```
:shallow

# Generates shallow routes for nested resource(s). When placed on a parent
# resource, generates shallow routes for all nested resources.

resources :posts, :shallow => true do
  resources :comments
end

# Is the same as:
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, :except => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
resources :comments, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# This allows URLs for resources that otherwise would be deeply nested such as a
# comment on a blog post like /posts/a-long-permalink/comments/1234 to be
# shortened to just /comments/1234.
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this from >rake routes

```
users_articles      GET    /articles(.:format)           {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users/articles"}
                    POST   /articles(.:format)           {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users/articles"}
new_users_article   GET    /articles/new(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users/articles"}
edit_users_article  GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)  {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users/articles"}
users_article       GET    /articles/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users/articles"}
                    PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users/articles"}
                    DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)       {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users/articles"}
```

We need this in our routes.rb

```
namespace :users, :path => '' do
  resources :articles
end
```

Note: I am using :namespace as that is what you stated.

Hope this helps.